# Posting to Flask app gives 404 even though route is defined

Tags: python, flask

I ran the following Flask app and tried to post to `/`, but I got a 404 response. The `/` route is defined, why doesn't it get handled?

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_post_request():
    return str(request.form)
```

```
C:\Python35\python.exe D:/Dropbox/dev/contact.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2017 20:46:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `app.run` blocks, no code is executed after it until the server is stopped. Make sure your app is completely set up before calling run. In this case, move the route definition above the call to `run`.

---

Flask 0.11 introduced [a more robust way to start applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/cli/) to avoid this and other common mistakes. Completely remove `app.run()`. Set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to your app's entry point, and call `flask run`.

```
FLASK_APP=contact.py flask run
```

You can also set `FLASK_DEBUG=1` to enable debug mode.

In Windows, use `set FLASK_APP=contact.py` to set environment variables instead.